# Faddeev-Popov integral for Chern-Simons theory

Tags: gauge-theory, path-integral, chern-simons-theory

This question is with respect to [this paper](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.cmp/1104178138) of Witten ([PDF](https://people.maths.ox.ac.uk/beem/papers/jones_polynomial_witten.pdf)). According to this paper the following path integral holds for a $3D$ manifold $M$

$$\int \mathcal{D}B\mathcal{D}\phi\exp\left(\int_M\operatorname{Tr} \phi D_i B^i+ \frac{k}{4 \pi} \int_M \operatorname{Tr}(B \wedge D B)\right) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\operatorname{det}(L_{-})}}$$

where $L_{-} =* d+d *$ where $d$ is the exterior derivative and $B$ is a one-form and $\phi$ is a three-form. Can someone explain how does this make sense?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I have an answer to this question. The operator $L_{-}$ is explicitly given by ([See paragraph above equation 3.11 here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/gr-qc/9406006.pdf)) $$L_{-} = *d \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0\\0 & 1\end{pmatrix} + d* \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1\\-1 & 0\end{pmatrix}$$ which acts on $(\alpha, \beta)$ where $\alpha$ is a 1-form and $\beta$ is a 3-form. Also, the operator above is the square root of the Laplacian as can be checked by looking at $(L_{-})^2$ $$(L_{-})^2 = I\cdot(d^{\dagger}d+d d^{\dagger})$$
where $d^{\dagger} = *d*$. The cross terms will cancel due to $d^2 = 0$. Now, consider the object given by $$\int_{M}\bar{\psi}L_{-}\psi$$ where $\psi = (\alpha, \beta)$ and $\bar{\psi} = (*\alpha, *\beta)^T$. Then we have
$$\int_{M}\bar{\psi}L_{-}\psi = \int_M(\alpha \wedge d\alpha +2\beta \wedge d^{\dagger}\alpha)$$
Now, take $(\alpha, \beta) = (B, \frac{k}{8\pi}\phi)$, then we reproduce the integral in question. Now, because $\bar{\psi}$ and $\psi$ commute with each other and are mere "transpose" of each other. The path integral in question is a "bosonic" gaussian integral and therefore, we have

$$\int [\mathcal{D}\psi] \exp\left(\int_{M}\bar{\psi}L_{-}\psi\right) \propto \frac{1}{\sqrt{\operatorname{det}(L_{-})}}$$